# Как в Redmine восстановить удаленную задачу?

Tags: mysql, redmine

Как можно в Redmine восстановить удаленную задачу? Если этого нельзя сделать через саму систему, то может можно как-то восстановить ее непосредственно через базу MySQL?

Comment: Именно задачу (task, а не issue)? Issue точно никак - http://www.redmine.org/issues/7900 И почему бы у них и не спросить? Всё же более подходящее место.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак. Задача удаляется из базы данных полностью, а не помечается как удаленная.